# How to use a Set <String> attribute in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm doing a chat and save the id of users who chat in a Set `<String>`, the problem is that when saving data in `DynamoDB` are automatically sorted in ascending order and I do not want to order it that way but not how to avoid it.

Comment: As per the documentation, the order of the set is not preserved. I think your interpretation is not correct.
Each value within a set must be unique. The order of the values within a set are not preserved; therefore, your applications must not rely on any particular order of elements within the set. Finally, DynamoDB does not support empty sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in practice, string sets do get ordered in alphabetical ascending order. However, as per @notionquest's comment, order is not guaranteed and cannot be relied upon. So, there is no way to avoid it. See details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes.SetTypes).

If, for example, you wanted to order by timestamp of the last user who participated in a chat, you'd have to store this data in a different way -- e.g. in a separate table with chat_id as the hash/partition key, timestamp as the range key, and user_id as an additional attribute. Then you could do a [query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Query) on a particular chat_id and return all the users who participated in chronological or reverse chronological order. This is just an example of an implementation. I don't know much about your use case, so it may not be the right one for you. Either way, I don't think that DynamoDB string sets are going to give you what you need.